# AudioKit connect External Bluetooth mic on IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, audiokit

Unable to connect external bluetooth mic as an input on AudioKit. I have "HeyMic" on checking available input devices it doesn't show up but on checking available output devices it shows up. Any idea on how we can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the use Audio kit to use the bluetooth option to be true.

You can use the below code

```
do { 
    AKSettings.useBluetooth = true
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord , with: [.allowBluetoothA2DP, .defaultToSpeaker, .allowAirPlay])
} catch {
    AKLog("Could not set session category.")
}
```